# Flash: ComboBox and List filled with XML data, then create links

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, combobox, flash-cs3

I am looking to generate a ComboBox with a list from xml, and then create links from those items. Secondly, I would like to to the same, but with a list and a second xml property.

ComboBox - with the list being the "name" property.

> http://hpn-marketing.com/drmc/content/index.php/specialty/flashxml/

List - with the list being the "name" property.

hpn-marketing.com/drmc/content/index.php/physician/flashxml/

Linking example:

```
  <specialty specialties_id="1" name="Pediatrics"/>
```

Would generate the link:
/content/index.php/physician/specialty/1

```
  <physician physician_id="1" permalink="" name="Fugate, James K. Jr, MD"...
```

Would generate the link:
/content/index.php/physician/single/1

Thanks in advance.

Adam

Comment: Can you show what code you have currently?

Comment: var xmlLoader:URLLoader  = new  URLLoader();
var xmlData:XML = new XML();
 
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
 
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://hpn-marketing.com/drmc/content/index.php/specialty/flashxml/"));
 
function LoadXML(e:Event):void {

xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
trace(xmlData);

}

Comment: Sorry, new to formatting on this site. 

I am only at the stage of calling the xml... really early.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on the right track:

```
<xsl:template match="specialty">
 <xsl:text>content/index.php/physician/</xsl:text>
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@specialties_id">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('specialty/', @specialties_id)" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('single/', @physician_id)" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</template>
```